# Symfony form with collection validation loose collection data and is not persisted

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have created 2 entities, one of which is used as a collection for the other.

On both entities i want to apply validation rules, but when i do so I have two problems with the validation of a collection :

if i fill all the mandatory fields right (in both main and collection), the entity is persisted,

but if i fail to fill one mandatory field,

1. i can never persist because even i fill afterwards ALL the mandatory
   fields i still have the validation error message for the collection
2. when i submit the (other) data filled in the collection are lost

What is strange (or not) is that if i fill the mandatory part for the main form, and not the ones for the collection, if i submit, the data from the main part is kept. but the other way around does not.

I really don't understand why this happens and don't see in other post the description of the same behavior.

My entities with annotations (relevant part) :

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="institution")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\InstitutionRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"},errorPath="name",message="An institution with the same name exists.")
 */
class Institution
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
   * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Vous devez entrer un nom pour l'institution")
   */
  private $name;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\InstitutionContact", mappedBy="institution", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
   * @Assert\Valid
   */
  protected $institutionContacts;
}


use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * InstitutionContact.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="institutioncontact", indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="FK_InstitutionContact_institutionId", columns={"institutionId"}),
 *      @ORM\Index(name="FK_InstitutionContact_userId", columns={"userId"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Simusante\SimustoryBundle\Repository\InstitutionContactRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"institution", "contact"},errorPath="departmentName",message="This contact and this institution are already connected."
 * )
 */
class InstitutionContact
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Institution", inversedBy="institutionContacts")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="institutionId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
   * @Assert\NotBlank(message="You have to choose an institution to link it to a contact")
   */
  private $institution;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="institutionContacts")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
   * @Assert\NotBlank(message="ou have to choose a contact to link it to an institution")
   */
  private $contact;
}
```

And in my formbuilder :

```
class InstitutionType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('name', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'name',
        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'mandatory'],
      ])
      ->add('institutionContacts', CollectionType::class, [
        'label' => 'user.institutionContact',
        'attr' => [
          'class' => 'collectiondata',
        ],
        'required' => true,
        'constraints' => new Valid(),
        'entry_type' => new InstitutionContactType($this->manager),
        'by_reference' => false,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
      ]);
      ...
  }
  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
      'data_class' => Institution::class,
      'translation_domain' => 'SimusanteSimustoryBundle',
      'attr'=>['novalidate'=>'novalidate'], //disable html5 validation
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: alas no, but for now i do a JS check for all mandatory field before submiting. It's dirty and not ideal, but i haven't found the solution sofar.